# eliminar valores repetidos sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo un problema en una consulta en sql server... tengo esta tabla donde de esta necesito eliminar valores repetidos (los marcados en azul) debido a la ultima columna ('hh''mm') ya intente con el DISTINCT pero aun asi me los muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si me di a entender espero me puedan ayudar.. este es el query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
n1,
n2, CONVERT (
    CHAR (10),
    maq_fechahora,
    108
) AS maq_fechahora, CONVERT (
    CHAR (5),
    maq_fechahora,
    108
) AS minu FROM
maq_equipos WHERE
maq_id = '020' AND CAST (maq_fechahora AS DATE) = '2018-10-17' AND maq_tip = 2 ORDER BY maq_fechahora ASC
```

Comment: Son repetidos por la ultima columna? y cuales datos de las otras columnas queres traer? como sabe la db cual es el repetido? o con cual quedarse? distinct busca filas exactamente iguales, y estas no lo son.

Comment: En dudas de este tipo en SQL es mejor que incluyas una muestra (en texto, no en imágen) de los datos que tiene la tabla origen y el resultado que deseas obtener.

Comment: exacto son repetidos por la ultima columna y quiero borrar esas filas pintadas en azul y quedarme con las filas blancas

Comment: @jachguate tengo como columnas n1,n2,hora completa y hora con minutos las horas con minutos se repiten n veces y esas filas son las que deseo eliminar sin importarme que los demas datos de las otras columnas NO se repitan algo que hace el distinc , por eso vi mas factible poner una imagen para que me pudiera entender mejor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente, buscas quedarte con una sola lectura por minuto, por el ejemplo que muestras, si tienes dos filas para el mismo minuto, quieres quedarte con la primera de las mismas cronológicamente hablando.

Una forma sencilla de resolverlo es generar un numerador para todas las filas mediante `ROW_NUMBER()`, con la particularidad que se reiniciará cada minuto: `PARTITION BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, maq_fechahora, 121), 16)`, por lo que finalmente ponemos todo en una subconsulta y solo recuperamos las filas dónde este contador sea 1.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (
        SELECT  n1,
            n2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, maq_fechahora, 121), 16) ORDER BY maq_fechahora) RN
            FROM    maq_equipos 
            WHERE   maq_id = '020' 
                AND CAST(maq_fechahora AS DATE) = '2018-10-17' 
                AND maq_tip = 2
    ) T
    WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Si te es indiferente que dato se muestre para las otras columnas, puedes *agrupar* por la columna que muestra *hh:mm* y aplicar alguna función que te devuelva un valor sobre las otras, como `min()` o `max()`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT   min(n1) n1
       , min(n2) n2
       , min(convert(char(10), maq_fechahora, 108)) AS maq_fechahora
       , convert(char(5), maq_fechahora, 108) AS minu 
  FROM maq_equipos 
 WHERE maq_id = '020' 
   AND CAST (maq_fechahora AS DATE) = '20181017' 
   AND maq_tip = 2 
 group by convert(char(5), maq_fechahora, 108) 
 ORDER BY convert(char(5), maq_fechahora, 108) ASC
```

En este caso, cabe aclarar que no estoy *eliminando* filas completas, sino mostrando algún valor para estas, esto implica que podría mostrarse un valor de la *primera* fila en una columna, y un valor de la *segunda* fila en la otra columna. Esto se debe a que estoy utilizando la función `min()` que simplemente devolverá el valor más pequeño. También puedes utilizar `max()`, u otras como `avg()`, etc.